# Ng repeat to refresh when there is change in custom sort function return value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using a custom sort function like this:

```
WidgetSections.itemsOrder = function (item) {
                if (WidgetSections.sortOnClosest)
                    return item.data.distance;
                else {
                    var order = OrdersItems.getOrder(WidgetSections.placesInfo.data.content.sortByItems || OrdersItems.ordersMap.Default);
                    if (order.order == 1)
                        return item.data[order.key];
                    else
                        return item.data['-' + order.key];
                }
            };
```

This doesn't change if there is change in my model - `WidgetSections.placesInfo`.

How to refresh the ng-repeat in this case? PS - I don't want to refresh the ng-repeat's list. That will blank up the list and reload it again by ajax which I dont want. I just want the sort to change.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle using this filter?

Comment: can you be a little more specific or can share the jsfiddle

Comment: please show all the code

Answer (score -2):

you can try to call this function inside of else part.

Comment: i dont think this will help